# Why is log.Printf() not printing?

Tags: go

I'm learning Go and came across this behavior I don't understand. When I do error checking and use log.Printf() I see the os error that I would normally see if I make that same error on the command line.

But when I use log.Fatal() the last log.Printf() does not print to the screen.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-2")

    stdoutStderr, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
        fmt.Println("Printing log fatal()")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Output %s\n", stdoutStderr)

}
```

I was expecting to see this output:

```
# go run main.go 
2019/05/14 11:23:34 Error: exit status 2
Output ls: invalid option -- '2'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
Printing log fatal()
2019/05/14 11:24:45 exit status 2
exit status 1
```

But My actual result is:

```
# go run main.go
2019/05/14 11:24:45 Error: exit status 2
Printing log fata()
2019/05/14 11:24:45 exit status 2
exit status 1
```

Comment: The code you have posted produces exactly the output I would expect. There are no lines of code that generate messages about ```ls``` or it's usage in your program.

Comment: When I comment out log.Fatal(err) I get this output which tells me that '2' is an invalid option to the 'ls' command:

Comment: # go run main.go 
2019/05/14 11:37:42 Error: exit status 2
Output ls: invalid option -- '2'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.

Comment: log.Fatal **terminates** your program. With log.Fatal the stdoutStderr is _never_ printed because that line is never reached.

Comment: but I'm calling log.Printf first and then log.Fatal.

Comment: why does commenting out log.Fatal() produce a different output for log.Printf()?

Comment: @momo106: because one calls `log.Fatal`, which exits the program immediately. The documentation for the `Fatal*` methods are all very concise: `Fatal is equivalent to l.Print() followed by a call to os.Exit(1)`

Comment: Because if you don't call ```log.Fatal``` your program continues on to fmt.Printf() which prints the error message for ls.

Comment: @JimB: so if i understand this correctly, printf is called but it does not complete quick enough before log.Fata() is called and thus the whole output of printf is not printed to the screen?

Comment: @momo106: How would you expect the last `Printf` to be called at all if you've already exited the program?

Comment: @JimB,@Volker,@JonGuiton thank you for the clarification. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

`log.Fatal` calls `os.Exit()` after printing the log message. So statements after `log.Fatal()` will not be called. I believe that is the reason you are not seeing output of `fmt.Printf("Output %s\n", stdoutStderr)` in the logs.

Comment: but I'm calling log.Printf first and then log.Fatal. When I do this it does not print the full output of log.Printf.

Comment: The calls to printf before the call to log.Fatal() **are** executed and **do** produce output. The calls to printf **after** log.Fatal() are never reached. log.Printf **does** print "Error exit status 2"

Comment: thank you, makes sense now.